# How to avoid flickering effect with javascript drag and drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I use the following javascript (with jQuery) to handle drag and drop on a script I am writing:

```
jsc.ui.dragging = false;
jsc.ui.drag_element = {};
$(".drag-target").mousedown(function() {
    jsc.ui.drag_element =  $(this);
    jsc.ui.dragging = true;
});
$("html").mousemove(function(e) {
    if(jsc.ui.dragging) {
        jsc.ui.drag_element.css({"position": "absolute", "top": e.clientY - 1, "left": e.clientX - 1, "z-index": "100"}); // - 1s are due to IE not leaving go otherwise
        $("#overlay").show(); // Overlay stops text beneath being selected. TODO Stop current elements text being selected.
    }
});
$(".drag-target").mouseup(function() {
    if(jsc.ui.dragging) {
        jsc.ui.dragging = false;
        jsc.ui.drag_element.css("z-index", "98");
        $("#overlay").hide();
    }
});
```

However when the object is being dragged, the text inside it has a flickering selection i.e. it is being selected on and off as the element is moved. Is there any way to prevent this, or hide it's effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason for not using [jQuery UI Draggable](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Draggable) ? Your code would look like that:

```
$(".drag-target").draggable();
```

You should at least check how it's build, it may help you to solve you flickering problem.

Comment: Is jQuery UI modular? If it is, the reason is lack of awareness about jQuery UI. However, I am not currently using jQuery UI, so adding an extra framework for one section seems overkill and if I need to use the entire framework, the reason is performance concerns.

Comment: Fully modular, you can select what you need here : http://jqueryui.com/download . 27k for jquery.ui.core and draggable, not that big in my opinion... Just give it a try and then decide if you want to keep it or try to solve this flickering issue ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think the extent of the effect depends on your hardware and video driver. To avoid it entirely, you could just draw a rectangle and then redraw the window when the mouse button is released.